# Exim4 autogenerated config not being generated properly on Debian Stretch

Tags: exim, mailman, debian-stretch

I have followed the instructions for installing `mailman3` on `Debian stretch` [here](https://github.com/maxking/docker-mailman) and copied the config files for `exim4` from the `core/assets/exim` directory to `/etc/exim4/conf.d/main`. However, when I run `update-exim4.conf` I get the following error;

```
2018-03-08 14:28:59 Exim configuration error in line 238 of /var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated.tmp:
  main option "mailman3_router" unknown
Invalid new configfile /var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated.tmp, not installing
/var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated.tmp to /var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated
```

After a bit of investigation I noticed that the `mailman3` `router` and `transport` configurations appear before the `begin router` and `begin transport` sections in the autogenerated config file. Is this expected? If not, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the 2 relevant conf files(455_mm3_router and 55_mm3_transport) not to /etc/exim4/conf.d/main but to /etc/exim4/conf.d/router and /etc/exim4/conf.d/transport.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for this! I can't believe no one else picked up on this and that it is wrongly specified in the documentation.